# IFSTREAM through parameter

Tags: c++, fstream, ifstream

I have a generic read function:

```
vector <string> GenericRead(ifstream &fin);
```

And a function:

```
int Rule(ifstream &fin)
{
    vector <string> obj2=GenericRead(fin);
}
```

Main:

```
ifstream fin;
fin.open("ex.txt");
vector<string>obj=GenericRead(fin); // works fine

Rule(fin) // no longer works, there are no elements in the function vector
```

Any solution to have the same result function vector?

Comment: I don't know if your code is exactly as shown but once you have read the first time, what has been read can't be read anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a stream is like a safe-pointer which runs over the file and stream the value it points at at the moment to some destination. in the end of `GenericRead` I suspect the stream "points" to the end of the file. you need to roll it back to the beggining of the file.

try `fin.seekg(std::ifstream::beg)` just before `Rule`.
disclaimer - you didn't post whole of your code, this is my (solid) assumption only.